# Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have already search for this, and i did find some topics discussing this problem, however none of which I felt like was the way I want to go, so therefore I hope to get a better sugestion here.

I want to get a timestamp from when a user was last updated.

```
$user->updated_at
```

If i run this, it gives me this error

```
Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int
```

This is because it returns a Carbon instance in Laravel 5.2, and I only need the timestamp.

```
Carbon {#303 ▼
  +"date": "2017-01-04 00:35:38.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

How do i fetch the "date" from the carbon instance, so I only get `2017-01-04 00:35:38` - I have no idea where .000000 comes from, as this doesn't show up in the database. In the MySQL database, it simply shows `2016-07-20 20:23:07` as of type `timestamp`.

Hope for some pointers and suggestions

Comment: What is the value you are looking for? What did you try so far?

Comment: I am looking for the value "2017-01-04 00:35:38" - Ive tried something like $user->updated_at->date and $user->updated_at(date) but all of these gives me nothing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Carbon` object has a `toDateTimeString` method you can use:

```
$user->updated_at->toDateTimeString();
```

It will give you the value `2017-01-04 00:35:38` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

While using Carbon library to perform multiple action using date.

Example :

Right now what you are doing.

```
dd($user->updated_at);

output : Carbon {#724 ▼
                  +"date": "2018-06-20 18:28:48.000000"
                  +"timezone_type": 3
                  +"timezone": "UTC"
                }
```

Suggest :

```
 dd($user->updated_at->toDateTimeString());

 output : 2018-06-20 18:28:48
```